# Glyph Stretching in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, symbols

I'm using `TeX Gyre Pagella Math` font and I noticed that integral symbol is too short, so I would like to stretch it. I can do with

```
\scaleto[1ex]{∫}{6ex}
```

for instance. I would like to correct it once for all, so that, every time I insert `∫` it is converted into the desired one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, the integral symbol in TeX Gyre Pagella Math is quite small; you can use a taller one from another font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range=\int]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[range={}]

\begin{document}
\[
\int_a^b f(x)\,dx
\]
\sbox0{$\displaystyle\int$}\the\dimexpr\ht0+\wd0\relax
--\the\dimexpr6ex\relax

\end{document}
```

[image]

The length printed below the formula show that the symbol is essentially as big as you'd like (only 1.3pt shorter).

If you don't have STIX Two Math, you can use XITS Math instead.